# Notational problem

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Please, how do I write the following  as a combination of a sum and a product:

$$ (c-a_1)(c-a_2)(c-a_3)b_1 + (c-a_2)(c-a_3)b_2+(c-a_3)b_3 ?$$
Also, how can I generalize it?

Comment: Can the person who down voted please explain why? Down voting without explaining doesn't help me improving the question if something is wrong it it. thanks.

Comment: You seem to be missing several words.  For example: `...following as a combination of ____ and a product`.  How exactly would you like it to appear?  You could perhaps choose to write it as $\sum\limits_{i=1}^3 \left( b_i \prod\limits_{j=i}^3 (c-a_j)\right)$, and could edit the upper bounds on each as desired to continue the pattern, but there is no way to tell if this is what you intend.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks for your helpful comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Still unsure if this is what you desire, but

$\sum\limits_{i=1}^3 \left( b_i \prod\limits_{j=i}^3 (c-a_j)\right) = (c-a_1)(c-a_2)(c-a_3)b_1+(c-a_2)(c-a_3)b_2+(c-a_3)b_3$

$\begin{array}{rl}\sum\limits_{i=1}^5 \left( b_i \prod\limits_{j=i}^5 (c-a_j)\right) =& (c-a_1)(c-a_2)(c-a_3)(c-a_4)(c-a_5)b_1 \\&+(c-a_2)(c-a_3)(c-a_4)(c-a_5)b_2\\&+ (c-a_3)(c-a_4)(c-a_5)b_3\\
&+(c-a_4)(c-a_5)b_4\\
&+(c-a_5)b_5\end{array}$

Et cetera.  Generalize to $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \left( b_i \prod\limits_{j=i}^n (c-a_j)\right)$

Comment: Thanks JMoravitz. That's exactly what I was after.

Comment: so what if I have instead $(c-a_2)(c-a_3)b_1 + (c-a_3)b_2 + b_3$? Would that be $$\sum\limits_{i=1}^3 \left( b_i \prod\limits_{j=i +1}^3 (c-a_j)\right)?$$

Comment: @Gorg seems correct, yes.

Comment: One more thing... For the last term I have $j$ going from 4 to 3$. Isn't that a problem?

Comment: @Gorg Technically not since there are no valid values of $j$ such that $j\geq 4$ and $j\leq 3$, it would evaluate as the [empty product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_product) which is by convention equal to $1$.  $\prod\limits_{j=4}^3\text{anything} = 1$